# Find the object of a field widget on a form

Tags: forms

I have two fields on a form. One is a select list with an Ajax callback on 'change'. When I am in callback, I want to call a function (addMoreAjax) on the second widget. For that I need to find the object that represents the second widget.

I can get the form object from the form_state, but I am unable to get the widget objects.

Any hint available? Many thanks for your support.

Regards
Christophe

Comment: [`WidgetBase::addMoreAjax()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21WidgetBase.php/function/WidgetBase%3A%3AaddMoreAjax/8.9.x) is static so you wouldn't need an object to invoke it - maybe you could add your current code to the question and explain what it's trying to do? That would probably make it easier to advise

Comment: `WidgetBase::addMoreAjax()` is also an AJAX callback. I am not sure it should be directly called.